# How to build a table view with collapsible sections?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I made a table view but I only want that the last section collapse when I touch it.
The problem here is that sometimes other sections collapse too.
What is wrong?

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        pushVentasTab() // pushVentaArticulos()
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        pushReporteDDia()
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {

        if SelectedIndex == indexPath.row
        {

            if self.isCollapce == false
            {
                self.isCollapce = true

            }else
            {
                self.isCollapce = false
            }
        }else{
            self.isCollapce = true
        }
    }
    self.SelectedIndex = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

Comment: You have to prevent the section from being collapsed in the code which performs the action. And you don't handle the `section` in `didSelectRow` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I assume by section you actually mean last *row* in the tableView? I would use `deleteRows(at:with:)`. See below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    //Check if last row
    if indexPath.row == dataSourceArray.count - 1 {
           tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

`dataSourceArray` is the array with which you populate your cells in `cellForRowAt`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `beginUpdates/endUpdates` has no effect at all in this case.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. Used to use this in a separate function